# Не получается загрузить фото в vk_api

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь загрузить фотографию в vk_api, но получаю ошибку "One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is invalid". Не понимаю где его взять и как оформить. В документации к методу который я использую этот параметр не упоминается. Прошу вашей помощи

```
import vk_api

from datetime import datetime
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

import requests







blue = 'primary'
white = 'secondary'
red = 'negative'
green = 'positive'



data = datetime.now()

sends = 0

print(f"""RASPISALSHIK BUILD 3.0
Начата новая сессия работы бота:
Time: {data.hour} : {data.minute}
""")

# Отправка клавиатуры
def sendkeyboard(id, text, keyboard):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0, 'keyboard': keyboard})


# Создание кнопок
def get_but(text, color):
    return {
        "action": {
            "type": "text",
            "payload": "{\"button\": \"" + "1" + "\"}",
            "label": f"{text}"
        },
        "color": f"{color}"
    }


# Функция рассылки обычных сообщений
def send(id, some_text):
    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": id, "message": some_text, "random_id": 0})

# Функция расылки сообщений с фотографиями
def senderp(id, text, pho):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, "attachment": pho, 'random_id': 0, })
def method(method, values):
    values["access_token"] = ''
    values["v"] = '5.131'
    try:
        query = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/' + method, params=values)
        return query
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
def upload_pic(filename):

    values = {'peer_id': 0}

    upload_url = method('photos.getMessagesUploadServer', values).json()["response"]["upload_url"]

    values = {'photo': open(filename, 'rb')}

    info_load = requests.post(upload_url, files=values).json()

    values = {
        'photo': info_load["photo"],
        'server': info_load["server"],
        'hash': info_load["hash"],
    }

    info_photo = method('photos.saveMessagesPhoto', values).json()["response"][0]

    return f'photo{info_photo["owner_id"]}_{info_photo["id"]}'



while True:

    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='')
    session_api = vk_session.get_api()
    longpool = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    for event in longpool.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me:
                msg = event.text.lower()
                id = event.user_id
                print(event.message_id)
                if msg == "фото":
                    print(vk.messages.getById(message_ids=event.message_id))
                    info = vk.messages.getById(message_ids=event.message_id)
                    photo_url = info['items'][0]['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][3]['url']
                    url = photo_url
                    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
                    open('fotoq.ico', 'wb').write(r.content)
                    print(photo_url)
                elif msg == 'с':
                    print(upload_pic('fotoq.ico'))
                else:
                    send(id, "Непонял вас, напиши слово «МЕНЮ», чтобы выбрать нужное тебе действие")
```